# Matlab: using 'writetable' to save workspace variables to .txt

Tags: matlab, export, long-integer, short

Want to save a large table using the friendly `writetable` command rather than `fprintf`. Unfortunately, the table values are `double` precision and `long` format which results in unreadable long numbers for a .txt file. Using the

```
format Style
```

command you can set the display in the command window. Matlab Help mentions:

`The format function affects only how numbers display in the Command Window, not how MATLAB® computes or saves them.`

Aside from going back to the slightly unwieldy `fprintf` command, is there a way to set my table values to `short` or `shortg` formats for export to .txt using `writetable`?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html `writetable outputs numeric variables using long g format, and categorical or character variables as unquoted strings in text files.` You are out of option.

Answer (score 1):

`fprintf` works quite well, you just have to define the format of your number

```
fid=fopen('mydatafile.txt','w'); % open a txt and set the property to write
data=rand(100,3); 
fprintf(fid,'%3.3f; %3.3f; %3.3f\n',data(:,:)); % print with 3 values, 3 of them after the comma, separated by ';'
fclose(fid) % close your txt
```

It can be that your Notepad displays that values in a row. Fur that purpose, you'd rather use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: Sorry mate - was too early in accepting your answer. Didn't notice that the array in your example was numeric. I'm working with `table` and fprintf doesn't work for that array type. 
Matlab throws out:
> Error using fprintf
> Function is not defined for 'table' inputs.